# ASIFormDataRequest returning error

Tags: iphone, upload, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I am getting a problem when i request to the server to upload and UImage

```
    NSString *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image.jpg"]; //UIImage *img = pickerImage;
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(postingImage, 0.5) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(postingImage, 0.5);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:serverURL];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setData:imageData withFileName:@"image.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];

    [request startSynchronous];
    NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %i",[request responseStatusCode]);
    NSLog(@"responseStatusString %@",[request responseString]);
```

it is giving this responses

> responseStatusCode 200
>
> responseStatusString Error: No file uploaded

Do any one know about this, where i am doing mistake,

your help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
[request setData:imageData withFileName:@"image.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

Try as

```
[request addData:imageData withFileName:@"image.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

I did same with help of ASIHTTPRequest and get images successfully posted on server. This should work I guess as it is working in one of my live project.

Comment: Thank you Jennis! I have tried with addData: but it is still showing "Error: No file uploaded", will it may be the problem in my server!?.